# Anything like the I-94 website for citizens?

Tags: taxes, customs

I'm trying to prepare my US taxes and want to check when I'm eligible for the foreign earned income exclusion. I'm a US citizen working in Canada. All I'm looking to do is to verify my border crossing information. CBP has the website https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/history-search to view your travel history.

As far as I can tell, the CBP site only returns results if you aren't a US citizen. Ideas?

Comment: Check your travel records?  Credit card statements? Phone records?

Comment: Maybe Google maps? My Android phone spies on my location and Google records it, so I can see where I was on any given day. I use this to find land border crossing dates (everything else is in a frequent flier account).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right in that most websites seem to suggest the Freedom of Information Requests for foreign citizens.

However, US citizens can indeed do this.

[Chris Guillebeau documents his process of doing this](https://chrisguillebeau.com/foia-request-for-travel-history/) and he's a US citizen (who has visited every country in the world).

He got back from his request:

> - A letter with an official response from the U.S. Customs and Border Protection
> - A long list (14 pages) of my international arrivals and departures
> - Another long list (8 pages) of various flight data, discussed below